# GA4 - Multiple coupons in the cart

Tags: google-tag-manager, google-analytics-4

How to create a tag to capture more than one coupon in the cart? "without concatenating the coupons"

In our store, our customers can add more than one coupon at a time to the cart.
but every time someone makes a different combination of coupons, GA4 understands that they are different coupons, as currently GA4 is concatenating when more than one coupon is used.